# How can I create a column from an element extracted from a column that is formed by a list of dictionaries?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How can I create a column in the dataset containing the text values from the hashtag column?
[image]

The code is as follows:

```
tw_data = pd.read_json('tw_hurricane_data.json',lines=True)

#creating an additional column with hashtag information obtained from the entities column
tw_data['hashtags'] = tw_data['entities'].apply(lambda x: x.get('hashtags'))
```

Now I have tw_data[hashtags'] column, but I do not know how to get the text value from it.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please provide a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: ```tw_data['hashtags'] = tw_data['entities'].apply(lambda x: x.get('hashtags'))``` Now I have tw_data[hashtags'] column, but I do not know how to get the text value from it.

Comment: Thanks for adding the code you tried. But we also need the data as text (not as image!)

Comment: Please provide a sample expected output. And also post the input dataframe as text, so we can use it to reproduce the issue.

Comment: it is a JSON file, containing information on 4000 tweets. I cannot copy it.

Answer (score 0):

`hastags` is a collection. You have not mentioned how to process the collection of values, so assumed that you want all values:

```py
tw_data[['hashtags']].apply(lambda x: [e["text"] for e in x["hastags"]], axis=1)
```